# Raw http request parsing

Tags: c#, httprequest

I am using windivert to capture tcp packet. I am successful to capture the packets by WinDivertSharp.dll. Now i want to parse the packet for only http request. To parse packet i am using the flowing code.

```
var index = BinaryMatch(messageBody, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n\r\n")) + 4;
var headers = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageBody, 0, index);
var memory = new MemoryStream(messageBody);
memory.Position = index;
string body = "";
if (headers.IndexOf("Content-Encoding: gzip") > 0)
{
    using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(memory, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (var decompressedMemory = new MemoryStream())
    {
       decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedMemory);
       decompressedMemory.Position = 0;
       body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedMemory.ToArray());
    }
 }
 else
 {
     body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBody, index, messageBody.Length - index);
 }
```

It working good for some webs. But for http request like from https://stackoverflow.com/ it is not working. Please help to decode 
http request for all kinds of web.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a long shot, but it might be related to `WinDivert` not decrypting responses from sites that use SSL/TLS (HTTPS) like [**https**://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/).

I would suggest you try and compare between sites that use HTTP and HTTPS.

Hope it helps!